# Bash, improve script to tail and trap quick log messages

Tags: bash, awk

For performance purposes I written a small bash script to trap certain key events in a CSV fashion, so that I can report them into Excel and make some basic formula, etc.
However it looks like some of these events are not always picked up and I am now looking for some improvements.
I suspect that the log file is generated quicker than what my script can actually do, so that in case 2 or more patterns are found , only one is picked and the others near to it lost.
Any ideas on how to rewrite it?

`while true; do tail -F $log_file | grep -m 1 -E "$x|$y" | awk '{print $1,"|",$2}';done`

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `-m 1` if you don't want `grep` to stop after the first match?

Comment: because in that way only the last printed line will be considered

Comment: Hm? `-m 1` tells grep to stop after the first match. If you have more than one potential match in the file and you want to process all of them then `-m 1` is sort-of *exactly* what you don't want.

Answer (score 0):

The question is vague, but this might help

```
tail -F "$log_file" | awk '$0~x || $0~y {print $1,"|",$2}' x="$x" y="$y"
```

- `while` does not seem needed here, tail will run forever anyway
- `awk` can do all of the logic that you have with grep

Comment: tail -F $log_file | awk '$0~x || $0~y {print $1,"|",$2}'
    awk: $0~x || $0~y {print $1,"|",$2}
    awk:        ^ syntax error

Thanks but it doesn't look good